# How to decode a linux kernel symbol

Tags: linux-kernel

To debug a problem I added some debugs in the kernel code to print the address at which a lock is taken, by calling __builtin_return_address(1).

How do I find the symbol (function name) corresponding to the address printed ?

Answer (score 0):

Use a Structure Like:

struct my_lock

{

spinlock_t mylock;

char function[64];

};

When you lock, save your function name there. And when you unlock, remove the function name. Also to avoid too many changes in code, you can have the string as global just for debug.

Comment: This will not work for me. I am recording the PC inside the lock function. That is why I am using  __builtin_return_address(1). At that time the calling function name isn't available.